Spicejet Calendar Handling - Using Selenium & Java
I am trying to select a particular month from the spicejet website from the "depart date" field using a while loop. When the particular month is reached, I am coming out of the while loop and then selecting a date from the particular month. In my below code, I am observing that the while loop is running in an infinite loop and not stopping when the particular month is reached.
public class CalendarHandling {

    static WebDriver driver;
    
    static By forwardArrow = By
            .xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @data-testid='svg-img']//*[name()='g' and @transform='translate(1 1)']");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowserUtil butil = new BrowserUtil();
        driver = butil.launchBrowser("chrome");
        butil.launchURL("https://www.spicejet.com/");
        selectdepartDate();

    }

    public static void selectdepartDate() {
        
        //click the departure date
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@data-testid='departure-date-dropdown-label-test-id']/div/div)[2]")).click();
        
        //store the departure month value
        String departMonthValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "//div[contains(@data-testid,'undefined-month')]/child::div/div[contains(normalize-space(),'June')]"))
                .getText();
        System.out.println(departMonthValue);

        //click the forward arrow until departure month is August 2024
        
        while (!departMonthValue.trim().contains("August 2024")) {
            driver.findElement(forwardArrow).click();
            departMonthValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                    "//div[contains(@data-testid,'undefined-month')]/child::div/div[contains(normalize-space(),'July')]"))
                    .getText();
        }

        //select the date
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-testid,'undefined-month')]//div[text()='28']")).click();

    }

}


I rewrote your method to be generic... or more flexible. It takes in a LocalDate which holds a day-month-year for the departure date. If the departure date is before today, it throws an exception. If the departure date is valid, it moves through the month panels until the desired day-month is visible and then clicks the correct day.
public void selectDepartureDate(LocalDate departureDate) {
    if (departureDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("The departure date must be in the future.");
    }

    // open the Departure Date calendar
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='departure-date-dropdown-label-test-id']"))).click();

    // move the calendar to the desired month
    int clicks = (int) LocalDate.now().until(departureDate, ChronoUnit.MONTHS) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < clicks; i++) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[data-testid='undefined-calendar-picker'] > div"))).click();
    }

    // select the desired day
    String month = departureDate.getMonth().toString();
    month = month.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + month.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    String dataTestId = String.format("undefined-month-%s-%s", month, departureDate.getYear());
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(String.format("//div[@data-testid='%s']//div[text()='%s']", dataTestId, departureDate.getDayOfMonth())))).click();
}

You call it like
String url = "https://www.spicejet.com";
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

LocalDate departureDate = LocalDate.of(2024, Month.AUGUST, 28);
selectDepartureDate(departureDate);

where WebDriver driver; is declared in the class but you can change this however you like. I just prefer to not have to pass driver to all my methods.
